# can we use cypress wait without then block?

Tags: cypress

https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/wait  - `cy.wait()` is used to wait for an arbitrary number of milliseconds.

What's the difference in the following two snippets

```js
// snippet-1

cy.wait(10*1000);
// other code
```

```js
// snippet - 2
cy.wait(10*1000).then(()=>{
// other code
})
```

I tried to run the following code to test how it is working and i got the output mentioned in the below image.

```
cy.wait(10 * 1000).then(() =>
  cy.log("This is inside wait()" + new Date().toLocaleTimeString())
);
cy.log("This is after wait()" + new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
```

These are the log results:

[image]

From the above image, it looks like we should add our code inside `.then` because that will be executed after `cy.wait` . I also have seen people writing their test cases just like `snippet-1`

Which one is correct and which one we should use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a better log, use a custom command to make a version that defers evaluating the value.

By providing a callback, the `new Date().toLocaleTimeString()` expression evaluates when you expect it to.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('logLazy', (thingToLog) => {
  if (typeof thingToLog === 'function') {
    cy.log(thingToLog())
  } else {
    cy.log(thingToLog)
  }
})

cy.wait(3_000).then(() =>
  cy.log("This is inside wait()" + new Date().toLocaleTimeString())
);
cy.log("This is after wait()" + new Date().toLocaleTimeString());

cy.wait(3_000).then(() =>
  cy.logLazy("This is LAZY LOG inside wait()" + new Date().toLocaleTimeString())
);
cy.logLazy(() => "This is LAZY LOG after wait()" + new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Cypress commands use the current value of variables and resolve function values when enqueuing commands. So, in your example, the commands are enqueued as `.wait()` and then the outer `.log()`. The value of the date string is calculated when the command is enqueued. The inner `.log()` is enqueued within the `.then()`, and thus has a later date string.

Either snippet is fine to use, but be aware of how the subsequent commands in your test will react. Are you manipulating some variable during your `.wait()`, and you would not want the original value to be used for your Cypress command? Probably a good idea to place that command within a `.then()` or some other Cypress command. Are you just interacting with the website and need to wait 10 seconds? You probably don't need to worry about placing commands inside `.then()`.